# using group by with sets

Tags: sql, join, group-by, impala

I might be asking the wrong question but I have been banging my head against this one for the last 12 hours (I'm a beginner) and can't quite find out how to get what I want:

I have the following table called "shipping_prices"

Here is what I want my query to do:
Return the cheapest price after comparing each carrier within each speed (so result is lower value for slow, med, fast).

I have written this query:

```
SELECT carrier, speed, MIN(price) AS min_price 
FROM(
   SELECT speed, total_wt, zone, carrier, price
   FROM(
      SELECT speed, zone, total_wt, carrier, price
      FROM (
        SELECT key_id, carrier, zone, total_wt, speed, price
    FROM shipping_prices
    WHERE (speed = 'slow' OR speed = 'med' OR speed = 'fast')
    ) AS return_price
      WHERE total_wt = 45
      ) AS return_speed
   WHERE zone = 8
   ) as return_zone
GROUP BY carrier, speed;
```

But this returns the 3 prices per carrier at each speed level.

```
+---------+-------+-----------+
| carrier | speed | min_price |
+---------+-------+-----------+
| fedex   | med   | 257.23    |
| fedex   | slow  | 52.87     |
| fedex   | fast  | 328.16    |
| ups     | med   | 269.08    |
| ups     | fast  | 347.81    |
| ups     | slow  | 91.41     |
| usps    | med   | 103.95    |
| usps    | fast  | 261.1     |
| usps    | slow  | 97.78     |
+---------+-------+-----------+
```

I'm trying to approach it with sub queries but maybe it would be more appropriate to use joins?

If you are going to answer, please explain as I want to understand. I come across these types of problems often and I have never been able to figure it out.

EDIT: this is being queried with Impala with data that was created in MySQL and imported using HIVE.

Thank you!

Comment: you should the dbms being used as well. like Oracle,SQL Server,MySQL,Postgres etc

Comment: no I don't think you understand. I want to find the MIN price within each speed level. And the reason I am grouping by speed is being if I don't, it returns an error GROUP by is required when you are using an aggregate function, in my case MIN()

Comment: So it should only show 3 rows? Also are there any other types of speed besides med, slow, fast?

Comment: no just 3 speeds (basically tiers for shipping)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with `MIN` window function. The sub-query gets the min price for each speed. `PARTITION BY speed` groups speed values and `MIN(price)` gets `min` price for each speed over that grouping. (Run the inner query to develop an intuitive understanding of how the window function works). Thereafter to just get that row, use a filtering condition.

```
SELECT carrier,speed,min_price
FROM (SELECT carrier, speed, price, MIN(price) OVER(PARTITION BY speed) as min_price
      FROM shipping_prices
      WHERE total_wt = 45 and zone = 8
     ) t
WHERE price=min_price
```

You can accomplish the same with a ranking function like `dense_rank` which handles ties when there are same min prices from different carriers at the same speed.

```
SELECT carrier,speed,price as min_price
FROM (SELECT carrier, speed, price, DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY speed ORDER BY price) as rnk
      FROM shipping_prices
      WHERE total_wt = 45 and zone = 8
     ) t
WHERE rnk=1
```

Comment: would you mind adding a bit more explanation. Specifically what the "OVER(PARTITION BY" part does. It would helpful if you have time to layout a step by step process (I understand inner queries are processed before outer queries) about what each part does (not expecting a book, maybe a line or two about what each part is doing)

Comment: Just a quick clarification to make sure I understand, the OVER(partition by speed) groups all the speed values into groups of slow, med, fast. Then the MIN(price) takes the minimum price from each one of those groupings (slow, med, fast)?

Comment: yes..it is logically equivalent to `select speed,min(price) from tbl group by speed`

Answer (score 1):

This query should work :

```
SELECT T1.carrier, T1.speed, T1.min_price 
    FROM (SELECT id 
              FROM shipping_pricing
              ORDER BY speed, min_price) AS Q1
    INNER JOIN shipping_pricing AS T1 ON T1.id = Q1.id
    GROUP BY T1.speed;
```

The sub-query sorts the data properly and returns only id's, main query joins the id's and get the data you want. By grouping sorted data, you know the values are the minimal values (or maximal if you sorted with `desc`)